# Using both Markers and Polylines in Google Maps API v3 (including auto-centre & auto-zoom)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to get a map showing with both Markers and Polylines joining the markers using Google Maps API v3. The code was complicated by the need to add auto-zooming and centering to the map (which is working).

The problem I have is that the markers show, but my attempts to show the polylines fail. Examples I've found either do one, or the other, or don't use auto-zoom & auto-centre.

I have a code example at http://jsfiddle.net/AgZCm/2/.

I've commented out the code that I believe should be activating the polylines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these changes to be done:

Declare this before the loop:

`var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );`

Include this within the for loop

`latlngbounds.extend( PitStops[ i ].latlng );`

And this after the loop:

`map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );`

And remove the second for loop

Something like this:

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );
for ( var i = 0; i < PitStops.length; i++ ) 
{
    new google.maps.Marker( {
        position: PitStops[ i ].latlng,
        map: map,
        title: PitStops[ i ].name
        } );
     path.push(PitStops[ i ].latlng);
     latlngbounds.extend( PitStops[ i ].latlng );
}
map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );
```

Comment: Thanks @Cdeez. The code's neater, but still doesn't seem to work. Updated code is at http://jsfiddle.net/23xd9/1/

Comment: Got it. On my updated version I changed var path = []; to var path = poly.getPath();

For anyone interested, the final working version is http://jsfiddle.net/23xd9/2/